# How to install Python 2.7 on Fedora 32 Linux when the newest version is Python 3.8?

Tags: fedora, python, dnf, pip

There is a software suite named amitools, which allows use of retro or vintage or whatever the term for nostalgia is these days, of AmigaOS programs directly from a Linux command line without using a full-scale emulator. It is written in Python.

I have installed the latest official version, only it's not working properly for me. One of the developers of amitools told me his version would work better. There's only one problem: his version is written in Python 2.7, whereas the official version is written in Python 3.8. These seem to be incompatible with each other.

I am running a Fedora 32 Linux system. I have both /usr/bin/python2 and /usr/bin/python3 installed. /usr/bin/python used to be a symlink to /usr/bin/python3, I changed it to /usr/bin/python3. But installing the software suite still isn't working.

Apparently I need the 2.7 version of "pip" (a Python installer program) to install the software suite. But "sudo dnf install python-pip" tells me I already have python-pip version 3.8 installed, and there doesn't seem to be a package called "python-pip2" or "python-pip2.7" available.

What I am trying to do here is install an older version of Python and pip alongside my current version, just to see if the developer's version of amitools works any better than the official version, because it's written in an older version of Python.

Comment: Does `dnf install python27` work?  https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1621892

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python2-pip` isn't available from the Fedora 32 repos as Python 2 is no longer supported. You can install it from the UnitedRPMs repo with the following but I wouldn't recommend it as it's not a supported repo:

```
rpm --import https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UnitedRPMs/unitedrpms/master/URPMS-GPG-PUBLICKEY-Fedora

yum install https://github.com/UnitedRPMs/unitedrpms/releases/download/17/unitedrpms-$(rpm -E %fedora)-17.fc$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm -y
```

The best option is to build it from the source code. You can get it from here: https://github.com/python/cpython/releases/tag/v2.7.18

In regards to your comment below, as a regular user:

```
pip install amitools==0.1.0 --user
```

Comment: `python2-pip` https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/rpminfo?rpmID=18903618 ?

Comment: `python2-pip ` https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1370021

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117262/discussion-on-answer-by-nasir-riley-how-to-install-python-2-7-on-fedora-32-linux).